# Mean-variance optimization - objective function formation with factor models

Tags: portfolio-optimization, factor-models, mean-variance

Tradition mean-variance optimization uses the following objective function in optimization:

$$
\mu w^T - \lambda w^T \Sigma w
$$

Which I'm trying to adapt to a factor model. I've come up with:

$$
f \mu w^T - \lambda w^T \Sigma w f f^T
$$

where:

- $f$ is the factor loadings (exposures)
- $\lambda$ is the risk aversion parameter
- $\mu$ is the factor returns
- $\Sigma$ is the factor variance-covariance matrix
- $w$ are the asset weights

Is this correct? I've tried to find literature detailing this adjustment but have not found anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This summary can be found among the CVXPY examples, [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/cvxgrp/cvx_short_course/blob/master/applications/portfolio_optimization.ipynb#scrollTo=mrXD2HSPxOHu).

[image]

Comment: In this example, the asset weights are only applied to the idiosyncratic component:

$w^TDw$ 

Shouldn't the asset weights be applied to the systematic risk (factor loadings) as well?

Comment: Through $f = F^{\mathrm{T}}w$ the weights are applied to the factor loadings, $F$, to get the factor exposures, $f$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. And then I assume the factor loadings and returns are already present in the term $\mu^T$

Answer (score 0):

That's not ideal. Why don't you just do the standard MV problem but including the factors themselves as assets? Since they generate positive alpha, the mean-variance problem will give them $w>0$, and your tangency portfolio would be higher.

Comment: If I used factors as assets I would be solving for factor weights. I'm trying to solve for asset weights.